# How to save a file to Dropbox using an URL to that file?

Tags: dropbox

Given an URL to any file online and Dropbox, can I save the file at the URL in Dropbox without downloading the file?

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. Are you trying to save a file that is already online in another cloud service? If so there is google drive. It may give you the option to save an attachment you received in google drive, usually for *.zip or documents.

Comment: I try to say about a site containing firefox.exe (http://www.filehippo.com/download_firefox/download/bd5494e10e8d57cf37d48b66f600464f/) i want this to my cloud storage withot downloading firefox.exe i.e. firefox.exe directly stored/saved in my cloud storage account.

Comment: I'm wondering why you would want that. You can always download the file from that link.

Comment: Anyway, check some of these: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-ways-send-files-dropbox-dropbox/

Comment: Yes i download files from that site. I like to know is any other way to save/download that file to cloud storage account withoud downloading that file to my computer. I'm not joking by asking such questions, I want to know is any other ways. That's all..

Comment: You'll need a browser extension for something like that, such as [Cloud Save](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cloud-save/dlbemabjbfhjcccahjioenmkgimjbbkd) (Google Chrome).

Answer (score 2):

Any of these services can do it:

- [ctrlq.org/save](http://ctrlq.org/save/) (Dropbox, Google Drive, SkyDrive, Box)
- [UploadtoDropbox.com](http://uploadtodropbox.com/) (up to 64mb files for free)
- [URL Droplet](https://www.urldroplet.com/) (up 30mb files for free)
- [sideCLOUDload](http://www.sidecloudload.com/) (up to 25mb files for free) (Dropbox, Email)

As well as the [Cloud Save](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cloud-save/dlbemabjbfhjcccahjioenmkgimjbbkd) Google Chrome Extension Al E. [mentioned in the comments](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/55191/how-to-save-a-file-to-an-online-cloud-storage-using-a-url-to-that-file/55376#comment44509_55191).

Comment: UploadtoDropbox seems to solve a different problem; it lets other people upload files to your Dropbox, but not from an URL.

Answer (score 0):

The best one and definitely without any Limits is [Ctrlq](http://ctrlq.org/save/)

it can even move a file size up to 1Gig (or more) to your cloud storage. but onedrive doesn't support that, you can use google drive as the save location. and this is kinda useful. for example to keep a backup of your website somewhere other than your hosting account in case of failure.

Comment: If you are affiliated with the company, please disclose that in your answer.  The first part of this reads like an advertisement.

Comment: i just often use it for my needs and i found it very useful comparing to other paid limited services and suggesting you to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [AutoFileMove WebURL feature](http://www.autofilemove.com/Support/Features), You can use any file URL and transfer to dropbox, ftp or amazon s3