# How to save file from a website to ADrive?

Tags: online-storage

I have read [How to save a file to an online cloud storage using a url to that file?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/55191/how-to-save-a-file-to-an-online-cloud-storage-using-a-url-to-that-file). I found the website that offers saving file to cloud, but it limited only save to DropBox or Google Drive.

I want to know how we can save file from a url to [ADrive](http://www.adrive.com). Adrive claim that it has feature to save file from other website, but I don't know what is the method and how to do it.

Any one know how to save file from other website to ADrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:**
[image: step1]

**Step 2**:
[image: step2]

**Step 3**:
[image: step3]

**Step 4**:
[image: step4]

**Step 5**:
[image: step5]

your file will be listed in folders/Home